# Kdevelop and git, commit button disabled

Tags: git

I installed KDevelop 4.2.3, enabled git plugin and created new project with git version control system. Repository was created in project directory and that's fine. However when I right click on file in project, then I choose option Git and I can do actions like add file to repo, git pull, git push etc., however some options like commit, branches etc. are disabled. How to make them work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that commiting to git work when I click on project name in Projects toolbar. Earlier I was trying to do it on single file in Documents toolbar.